# active directory: what is the semantic of the integer values associated to DNS SRV records?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

Starting from the following example (citated on [samba wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setup_a_Samba_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller#Testing_DNS)):

```
$host -t SRV _ldap._tcp.samdom.example.com.
_ldap._tcp.samdom.example.com has SRV record 0 100 389 dc1.samdom.example.com.
```

What do the integers in the response mean?

389 is likely the TCP port involved, but 0? and 100?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's have a look at RFC 2782, [A DNS RR for specifying the location of services (DNS SRV)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2782.txt)

> The format of the SRV RR
>
> Here is the format of the SRV RR, whose DNS type code is 33:
>
> _Service._Proto.Name TTL Class SRV Priority Weight Port Target

So although your example does not list TTL, we do know its class is IN and that its type is SRV...

_ldap._tcp.samdom.example.com 0 100 389 dc1.samdom.example.com.

- Name _ldap._tcp.samdom.example.com
- Priority 0
- Weight 100
- Port 389
- Target dc1.samdom.example.com.

[image: From AD Windows DC]

Answer (score 5):

Priority and weight:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record

Lower priority (0) is more preferred.